# Struggling with form validation not executing PHP

Tags: php, validation

Hello Guy's please assist, am having validation problem. so basically if i don't validate any of the form the form execute perfectly, how ever once i validate it the form just returned with form and it value.

** here is my code **

```
             $error[] = "";
         if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

             $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
             $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
             $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
             $user_type = trim($_POST['user_type']);
             $email = trim($_POST['email']);
             $created_at = trim($_POST['created_at']);
             $password = trim($_POST['password']);
             $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);

             // validate form field
             if (empty($firstname)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your first name';
             } else {
                 if (strlen($firstname) < 3) {
                     $error[] = 'First Name is too short';
                 }
             }
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname)) {
                 $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
             if (empty($lastname)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your last name';
             } else {
                 if (strlen($lastname) < 3) {
                     $error[] = 'Last Name is too short';
                 }
             }
             // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lastname)) {
                 $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
             }
             if (empty($user_name)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your username';
             } else {
                 if (strlen($user_name) < 3) {
                     $error[] = 'UserName is too short';
                 }
             }
             // set email filter validation 
             if (empty($email)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your email address';
             } else {
                 //email validation
                 if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                     $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
                 }
             }
             if (empty($password)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please create a password';
             } else {
                 if (strlen($password) < 6) {
                     $error[] = 'Password is too short';
                 }
                 if (strlen($password) > 15) {
                     $error[] = 'Password is too long';
                 }
                 if (!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password)) {
                     $error[] = "Password must include at least one CAPS! ";
                 } else {
                     if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
                         $error[] = "Password must include at least one NUMBER! ";
                     }
                 }
             }
             // set field validation for confirm password
             if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                 $error[] = 'Field empty, please confirm your password';
             } else {
                 if ($password != $confirm_password) {
                     $error[] = 'Error... Passwords do not match';
                 }
             }

             //if no errors have been created carry on
             if (!isset($error)) {

                 $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                 $created_at = date('Y-m-d');
                 if (!($stmt = $con - > prepare("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, user_name, user_type, email, password, created_at) 
                             VALUES( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )
                             "))) {
                             echo "Prepare failed: (".$con - > errno.
                             ")".$con - > error;
                         }
                         if (!$stmt - > bind_param('sssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password_hash, $created_at)) {
                             echo "Binding paramaters failed:(".$stmt - > errno.
                             ")".$stmt - > error;
                         }
                         if (!$stmt - > execute()) {
                             echo "Execute failed: (".$stmt - > errno.
                             ")".$stmt - > error;
                         }
                         $stmt - > close();
                         if ($stmt) {
                             $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully registered, login here!";
                             header('Location: index.php');
                             exit;
                         } else {
                             $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Some error, try again";
                             header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

I don't no if you can see what i can't am not seeing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix your code indention. It's really really hard to read nested if's when the indention is inconsistent and a mess.

Comment: it's was fix perfectly before, until the validation was driving me mad. sorry about that.

Comment: `!isset($error)` is always `false`

Comment: _Side note:_ There are a lot of people that have first- and last names that's only two characters long, and others that have names with other characters than just a-z and space. Your validation will tell them that their names are wrong. Seems a bit mean.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson... Very good point there... i will take that on board.

Comment: Have also improve my code indentation for better reading... hopefully it helps

Comment: I think that @u_mulder already should have solved your issues in his answer, though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson... Yeah the below works great... thanks guy's for the contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset` checks that varialbe **is set** that is `it has a value`

Your `if(!isset($error)){` will never be **true**. Because you set value for `$error` earlier in your script:

```
$error[] = "";
```

This line is **wrong** too. You add an empty string to `$error`. Why? Just declare it as empty array:

```
$error = [];
```

After that you can check emptiness of `$error` witn `empty()` instead of `isset`:

```
//if no errors have been created carry on
if(empty($error)) {
```

Comment: thanks for your input... i actually didn't see that. you have a point with setting the value for `$error[] = "";`... i didn't use it like that on my log-in page and it works.

Comment: Allow me to make the changes now... one moment

Comment: beautiful, this work perfectly... thanks for seeing it better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest laying it out slightly different.

First perform the checks when you detect the form has been posted. If you do this before any content is output you can still send headers and perform other useful actions.

```
$sError     = ""; 
$sFirstName = '';

// check if post has been made
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //check for content and a non empty string
    if(isset($_POST['FirstName']) && $_POST['FirstName'] != ''){

        // perform any other validation tasks here
        if(strlen($_POST['FirstName'] > 3){

            $sFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
        }else{
             $sError .= "[FirstNameLength]";
        }

    }

    // if firstname hasnt been set we can add to error string
    if($sFirstName == '')
       $sError .= "[FirstName]";


    // if nothing in sError go ahead with the action 
    if($sError = ""){

    }
```

Then later after you have included your header etc, you can check the sError var and output any error messages;

```
if($sError !== ""){
    if( 
        strpos($sError, '[FirstName]') !== false ||
        strpos($sError, '[LastName]') !== false
    ){
        echo"<div class=\"statusMessage alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><ul>";

        if(strpos($sError, '[FirstName]') !== false){
            echo "<li>You must enter a first name</li>";
        }
        if(strpos($sError, '[FirstNameLength]') !== false){
            // just an example of another check, firstname could be 1 char!
            echo "<li>Your first name is too short, please enter full name</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul></div>";
    }
}




// success messages
if(isset($_GET['successMessage'])){
    if($_GET['successMessage'] === "info-updated"){
        echo"<div>Info Updated.</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: have tried this method way back when i was first validating my code, but don't work for me much, personally. Thanks for your input though.